# ios 7 tabbar controller -> morenavigationcontroller barStyle & color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set the color of the tabbar controller to black for iOS7. all view controllers are dark black as expect except for morenavigationcontroller. the navigation bar and the tabbar part of the morenavigation controller is not as black as the others. its dark gray or light black. :) anyit doesnt match to other viewcontrollers.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

any clue on how to color it black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't touch the `translucent`, it is `YES`by default in iOS7.

you need to set it to NO if you want a solid black:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: When I add this, my UITableView no longer "stretches" to fill the whole screen on iPhone 5 and I'm left with blank space... any idea what I might be doing wrong?